How to get current parameter value during optimization in AnyLogic?
According to documentation, a current parameter value can be obtained with double getCurrentParamValue(IVariable parameter). What should I write inside this function to get a value of parameter named x?

During the optimization experiment, the parameters can be acessed via the root object using root.x or root.get_x(), acessing the parameter directly
